# MQTT authorization error self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, mqtt, x509certificate

Good day, everyone. I have a problem with MQTT authorization. I've created the certificate and uploaded it to the MQTT broker (Yandex-cloud). The certificate was generated by OpenSSL. But when I try to connect with it, I get the problem "self signed certificate in certificate chain". I've already tried a lot of StackOverflow fixes but they didn't help me.

```
const options = {
  ca: fs.readFileSync('***/yandex.pem'),
};
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://mqtt.cloud.yandex.net:8883', options);


Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
}
```

UPD: Certificate generation

```
$ openssl req -x509 \
-newkey rsa:4096 \
-keyout key.pem \
-out cert.pem \
-nodes \
-days 365 \
-subj '/CN=localhost'
```

Comment: rejectUnauthorized: false is not suitable for me

Comment: Edit the question to include details of how you created the certificate, as it is we would have to guess which isn't helpful